# An old anime with a scene of a young man struggling to reach the top of a glass staircase

Tags: video-girl-ai

Any help solving this would be appreciated. It's been so long, I can't even tell if I actually saw this, or if it was some sort of fever-dream that I made up and will never track down. Here's the scene:

A young man is struggling to reach the top of a glass spiral staircase (maybe to save a young woman from something evil at the top?), and the glass steps under his feet keep cracking but not breaking all the way (and maybe cutting his bare feet?).

This really felt like I caught just the climax, and I don't remember anything before or after for context, unfortunately. That sequence has just always stuck with me over the years, I need to get closure and find out what it was!

Comment: @Gao That's exactly it! Thank you! I've definitely done similar searches in the past looking for this clip, but maybe I was too hung up on my incorrect recollection of the staircase being spiral. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 7):

A simple googling of the terms "anime glass staircase" brought me to a discussion page on:

**Video Girl Ai** (1992)

The scene is from [Episode 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgqWn9pNbmc&t=20m0s), the last episode of the OVA, and the only thing not matching your descriptions is that the staircase is not spiral: it is straight.

[image]

Synopsis (ANN):

> Because Youta worried for another instead of dwelling on his own broken heart, he happened upon a very special video store that only the pure of heart can see. There, he buys what he thinks is a normal erotic video - until a girl climbs out of his television set. Her name is Ai, and thanks to a broken VCR, her personality is a little glitchy. Still, it's her job to help Youta feel better, and perhaps even help him get the girl of his dreams, even if Ai herself might be falling for him as well.

Comment: just added the `&t=` argument to the page so it starts at 20 minutes (ie. `&t=20m0s`)